# Django-pyodbc SQL Server/freetds server connection problems on linux

Tags: sql-server, django, pyodbc, freetds, django-pyodbc

> Error: ('IM002', '[IM002]
>   [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source
>   name not found, and no default driver
>   specified (0) (SQLDriverConnectW)')

I'm migrating from developing on a windows development machine to Linux machine in production and I'm having issues with the freetds driver. As far as I can tell that error message means it can't find the driver. I can connect via the cli via sqsh and tsql.  I've setup my settings.py as such.

```
   'bc2db': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'DataTEST',
        'USER': 'appuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'PASS',
        'HOST': 'bc2.domain.com',
        'options': {
            'driver': 'FreeTDS',
            }
    },
```

Does anyone have any SQL Server experience with django? do I have to use a dns? (how would I format that?)

Comment: I am having the same problem my friend!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to use one of the [supported configurations](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/prepodbc.htm) as supported by the freetds driver. I ended up putting the host information in the odbc.ini. The linked documentation has good examples over a few pages.

Comment: I downloaded their product, and when I ran:
isql -v mydsn [USERNAME] [PASSWORD]

I got an error:
[unixODBC][Easysoft][SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]General error: General error: Failed to initialise licensing - No valid licenses for this product found,

Comment: can you post how your final configuration ended up like?

Comment: too bad... I was fighting today with this same problem, but I already solved it. Thanks, anyway! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a database connection for SQL Server and django in case someone needs it, this is how it will look in the settings.py.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'YourDBname',
        'USER': 'YourUsername',    
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'OPTIONS' : {
            'driver': 'SQL Native Client',
            'dsn': 'YourDSNname',
            'MARS_Connection': True,
        },
    },    
}
```

Further information [here...](http://django-mssql.readthedocs.org/en/1.2/quickstart.html)